# cakephp 3.0 get values in two columns as one

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to get multiple of two columns as value but in cakephp 3.0 it given a error

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (Transactions__amount * PluTransaction FROM `transactions` `Transactions` LEF'

```
  $result =  $this->Transaction->find('all', array(
      'conditions' => [
        'Transactions.house_id' => $houseId]
    ))->join([
      [
        'alias' => 'PluTransaction',
        'table' => 'plu_transactions',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => 'PluTransaction.transaction_id = Transactions.id'
      ]
      ])->select(['Transactions.id',
    '(Transactions.amount * PluTransaction.item_quantity) AS TOTAL',  
  ]);
```

Comment: error given from '(Transactions.amount * PluTransaction.item_quantity) AS TOTAL' seems cakephp adding AS :(

Comment: Could you share us the result SQL? and for the join you have doble "["

Comment: I have multiple join statements , in my question I added sql error that i am getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you define calculated columns, please refer to the docs

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Raw Expressions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions)**

You must use the `key => value` format to define the alias and the expression separately.

```
$query = $this->Transaction->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        'Transactions.house_id' => $houseId
    ]
]);
$query
    ->select([
        'Transactions.id',
        'TOTAL' => $query->newExpr('Transactions.amount * PluTransaction.item_quantity')
    ])
    ->join(/* ... */)
    // ...
```