# How can I use arithmetic operators in cakephp 3 find methods?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to construct a query with a multiplication like this:

```
SELECT 
Jobs.id AS `Jobs__id`, 
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Jobs.date_last_done)) * Jobs.share AS `priority` 
FROM jobs Jobs 
ORDER BY priority DESC
```

Virtual fields don't seem to work in this situation, because it is impossible to use ORDER BY with virtual fields.

Any help much appreciated!

I found one possible solution, but it is bit hacky. In a custom finder model of my JobsTable I wrote this:

```
public function findWithPriority(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query->select([
        'id', 
        'priority' => $query->func()->round(['(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Jobs.date_last_done)) *  Jobs.share' => 'literal']),
    ])
    ->order(['priority' => 'DESC']);
    return $query;
}
```

I just put my multiplication in a round-function, which lets me execute literal statements. However the round-function in and of itself is just superfluous for my purposes, so I think there got to be a better solution?

Comment: You could use a [**raw expression**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31316822/1392379).

Comment: Thanks @ndm, that is what I am looking for!